# Shopify APP: Apply discount to cart item propramatically

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm looking for a solution (a Shopify app) that can help me to apply the discount rules on the Shopify cart items.
There should be a AJAX request to the Shopify app before redirect to the Checkout page.

Please let me know if you have any ideas/solutions.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: If you're on Shopify Plus the easiest is to use Shopify Script

Comment: oh, so it's available in Plus plan only?